# Keep my app running while running an external process

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here's the my problem, I'm running an external process within unity using this code:

```
    MyProcess = new Process();
    MyProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    MyProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    MyProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    //MyProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    //MyProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    MyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = DataPath + "myfile.bat";
    MyProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceived);
    MyProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    MyProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    MyProcess.Start();
    MyProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
    string Output = MyProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log(Output);

    MyProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Everything is fine except the process in the bat file takes almost 1-2 minutes in which my app totally freezes. I just want to run an animation while it's being processed (not proceed with code)..

I tried Threading but it runs the thread in the background and didn't find any successful way to stop the app from proceeding with the code before it finishes, and when I tried an empty loop while Thread.IsAwake is false the app freezes again.

Any Ideas?

Thank You,

Comment: where is the animation?

Comment: It's a 2D animation on the UI

Comment: This is not unityscript, please don't tag C# unity questions with the unityscript tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `MyProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();` you should not be calling `MyProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();`. Also you can't call `MyProcess.WaitForExit()` either, that will lock up the program.

What you should instead is subscribe to the `Exited` event. However I believe the event will be raised on a background thread so you will need to use some other mechanism to tell the UI that it is done reading because you can't directly talk to components from threads other than the UI thread.

What I recommend is you use [`WaitUntil`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html) to watch a variable and you set that variable when Exited has fired.

```
private IEnumerator StartAndWaitForProcess()
{
    bool programFinished = false;
    var waitItem = new WaitUntil(() => programFinished);
    MyProcess = new Process();
    MyProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    MyProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    MyProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    //MyProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    //MyProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    MyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = DataPath + "myfile.bat";
    MyProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceived);
    MyProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    MyProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    //Sets the bool to true when the event fires.
    MyProcess.Exited += (obj, args) => programFinished = true;

    MyProcess.Start();
    MyProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
    //string Output = MyProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); //This locks up the UI till the program closes. 
    //UnityEngine.Debug.Log(Output); This log should be in the DataReceived function.

    //MyProcess.WaitForExit(); This also locks up the UI

    //This waits for programFinished to become true.
    yield return waitItem;
}
```

The function `StartAndWaitForProcess()` will need to be called with a `StartCoroutine`, you can wait for the coroutine to finish and stop your animation then.